# Interchange qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer <-> osgeo.ogr.Layer

Tags: pyqgis, ogr, vector-layer

Is it possible to convert qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer instance to osgeo.ogr.Layer instance and vice versa in python script ?